# rendering in context of web development

Tags: rendering

I don't quite understand the meaning of **rendering** in context of web development. When I read about browsers architecture,rendering is something about displaying fetched content from the internet. On the other hand, there are definitions of **client and server rendering** (with no browsers mentioned). For example in **Backbone.View** class we have **render** method that is responsible for connecting data with markup.

Outside of web-development context, there is a Wiki definition:

> Rendering is the process of generating an image from a model (or
>   models in what collectively could be called a scene file), by means of computer programs. Also, the results of such a model can be called a rendering

How to properly understand this concept ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rendering is the process of gathering data (if any) and load the associated templates (or just send the output directly). Then apply the gathered data to the associated templates. The final output is sent to the user.

This concept is quite the same for both client and server. In client, when using Backbone.View, the `render` method is more like a conventional method where you can put your rendering logic in it. You can call it `draw`, it is totally ok. The main concept of Backbone.View is that you get your data from somewhere (mostly from `this.model`) and then load the associated templates (from the DOM using $('#template-id').html() or using the text plugin of `requirejs` to load templates using AJAX requests). After you have the data and template, you can use your own template engine and "make" the final output then append it to the DOM so that users can see it

The server will probably do the same thing, and then send back the final output so that the browser can "render" it. There are some minor differences, though. In client side, you load your templates through ajax requests or from the DOM, in server side, you will probably load your templates from hard drive. As for the data, in client side, you get your data by using ajax requests or the data is already embedded to the response by the server (by inline javascript objects). In server side, you will get your data from the database (or cache) or from some 3rd party services

Comment: That is a good answer when talking about one aspect of rendering ( where the rendering is happening ). After reading, I think about HTML as a kind of templating language, which is embedded in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to provide a general meaning to this query.

*Rendering* in programming refers to processing any piece of code that we have written and showing the result of it.

Eg: I could write a web page which may consists of dropdowns, checkboxes and any few other UI controls. Now when I load this page in browser I expect to see all the controls properly loaded. If something is missing then I could say it as page rendering is failing.

It's just the process of producing the results out of the piece of code that we have written either in client side or server side.

Answer (score 2):

Studying different array methods, I came across the word "render" in explanation of understanding the concept and by definition by breaking the word down in a grammatical format: it means to repeat, yield, to give back. You can only give back what has been collected through extraction 'such as data' and output that information back out. Hopes this helps. 1st time answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words:
rendering means taking your code and processing it to show on the browser, as an HTML file.

for example, you written a code

```
import cat.png
```

now your code will be rendered by the browser and it'll show you a cat image on the browser.

Rendering of a web page means different for web server and browser.

**Rendering by a Server**

in terms of web server, your code will be rendered and give you an HTML output by your web server.

something like this

```
<img src="cat.png">
```

**Rendering by a Browser**

in terms of web browser, taking the HTML code and show it into the browser, is called rendering by a browser.

something like

** image of the cat **

Answer (score 0):

**When talking only about browser architecture, rendering means the definition you've shown**: generating an image from a description like a PNG file or HTML+CSS documents

> Rendering is the process of *generating an image* from a model by means of a computer program.
> ~ [Rendering (computer graphics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics)) article on Wikipedia

or

> Rendering, that is *display* of the requested contents *on the browser screen*.
> ~ [How browsers work](https://web.dev/articles/howbrowserswork) article on [web.dev](https://web.dev/) by Tali Garsiel, 2011

This rendering process  in the browser can be modeled as follows. ([Chrome DevRel](https://web.dev/articles/howbrowserswork#the_main_flow), [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work))

[image]

1. Parse HTML and CSS into tree data structures: DOM and CSSOM
2. Merge both trees into one: Render Tree
3. Calculate the layout (add size and position to each visible element in the tree)
4. Paint elements on the screen
5. Execute JavaScript for interactivity (optional)

=> The image on the browser screen is generated from a description (your HTML and CSS files).
      And from the resulting models (the "OM" in DOM and CSSOM stands for Object *Model*).

> Note that DOM and CSSOM can directly be created and manipulated with JavaScript, without having HTML and CSS. Many Frontend-Frameworks do this.

---

**But in the context of web development, rendering *additionally* means the step before:** generating the description (HTML+CSS) from another description (JavaScript/PHP/... code + data).

> Rendering is *the process of generating HTML markup* to display web pages in the browser. 
> ~ [Rendering on the Web](https://www.netlify.com/blog/the-acronyms-of-rendering/) article on Netlify Blog, 2023

or

> Rendering is *the process of turning data and code into HTML*, that can be seen by the end user
> ~ [10 Rendering Patterns for Web Apps 0:20](https://youtu.be/Dkx5ydvtpCA?t=20) video by Fireship

The Rendering Patterns you mentioned ([Server-Side Rendering](https://web.dev/articles/rendering-on-the-web#server-side_rendering) and [Client-Side Rendering](https://web.dev/articles/rendering-on-the-web#client-side_rendering)) have gotten their name from the location *where* the HTML is generated/"rendered" (Client vs. Server).

But actually, the problem that rendering patterns solve is not only *where*, but also *when* HTML/CSS or directly DOM/CSSOM are generated.

[image]

- Static Site Generation ([SSG](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rendering-patterns/#static-site-generation-ssg-)) -> HTML & CSS is generated *(when?) way in advance*, *(where?) on some dev's local machine* or *a build server*
- Server-Side Rendering ([SSR](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rendering-patterns/#server-side-rendering-ssr-)) -> HTML & CSS is generated *(when?) at request*, *(where?) on the server*
- Client-Side Rendering ([CSR](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rendering-patterns/#single-page-applications-spas-with-client-side-rendering-csr-)) -> DOM & CSSOM are generated *(when?) after request*, *(where?) on the client* (in the browser)

---

#### Thus, Rendering in web development is defined as...

...any creation or modification of HTML and CSS files, or of DOM and CSSOM, as well as all subsequent actions of the browser, that are necessary to draw the image on the screen.

> Some make a [further distinction](https://medium.com/simform-engineering/react-re-rendering-exploring-what-why-and-how-d180d5305892) between solely *manipulating* existing HTML/CSS or DOM/CSSOM ("Re-Rendering") and *creating it from scratch* ("Initial Rendering").