# What does "rendering" mean in the context of server side rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I know that rendering is the process in which the browser use HTML, CSS, Js code to show something on the screen, something visible to the user

But in server side rendering context, i feel that this is different, as i understand, in SSR, rendering means just creating a full HTML document that is sent to the client browser with js bundle which the browser use to show something visible to the user

Now is just generating a HTML document in the server is considered a form of rendering?? or something is not accurate here since it doesn't render anything actually??

Comment: Yes SSR is rendering HTML and show it to user)

Comment: No, the browser takes over that mission to show something to the user not the sever, the server only generates the full document that is not interactive until the browser run the js bundle after rendering that document

Comment: Yes, server doesn't "show" anything, browser does.

Comment: Rendering means different things in graphics/browser architecture and in web development. I wrote a [detailed answer on the meaning of rendering here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518951/rendering-in-context-of-web-development/78061326#78061326).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now is just generating a HTML document in the server is considered a form of rendering?

Yes.

Even if you just have a text template where you replace placeholders, e.g.

```
const response = `<html><title>${title}</title><body>${message}</body></html>`;
```

that could be considered rendering (since it turns the template into the final document to be transmitted).

Comment: Few words but explain everything, thank you

Answer (score 2):

In React, if you create your app using `create-react-app` then after building the project it will have the index.html file and js attached to it. `index.html` is empty only the `<div id="root"></div>` is present.

When you serve this build folder from a server, the server just sends the index.html file as it is and the browser will attach everything starting from `<div id="root"></div>` when the attached js loads in the browser. This is client-side rendering.

In the context of React `server-side rendering` is your index.html should have rendered more content inside the `index.html` file before sent to the browser. By simply setting up a Node server you can do a `ReactDOM.renderToString(App)` to render the current page as a string and attached to `index.html` like `<div id="root">{ReactDOM.renderToString(App)}</div>`. This is server-side rendering.
When this received by the browser(client) it attaches all of the rest (event listers.. etc).

When you have set up this is properly your website is isomorphic (behaves same in the client or the server)