# What is rendering in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning reactjs and I'm a complete beginner. I am facing a problem with the term "rendering", what does it actually means?? I don't understand what it means to render something. Please provide me with a clear explanation.
Thank you.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+render+react.js&sca_esv=560664892&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS884US884&sxsrf=AB5stBi_Kdyf-Wq5Q68tqo0Rip5373HtvQ%3A1693240081609&ei=EcvsZOrZJNepptQPwPyRiA8&ved=0ahUKEwiqptXs4v-AAxXXlIkEHUB-BPEQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=define+render+react.js&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFmRlZmluZSByZW5kZXIgcmVhY3QuanMyBhAAGBYYHjIIEAAYigUYhgMyCBAAGIoFGIYDMggQABiKBRiGAzIIEAAYigUYhgMyCBAAGIoFGIYDSIQcUJAKWMYZcAF4AZABAJgBiAGgAZkHqgEDNi4zuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIKEAAYRxjWBBiwA8ICChAAGIoFGLADGEPCAgUQABiABMICBxAAGIAEGArCAggQABgWGB4YD-IDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgo&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

Comment: Rendering means different things in graphics/browser architecture and in web development. I wrote a detailed answer on the [meaning of rendering here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518951/rendering-in-context-of-web-development/78061326#78061326).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering something is when you show it to the page; like, if I rendered:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
```

then my page would show an `h1` element with "Title" in it.

Going more in depth, I would say that rendering is what React uses to update the Virtual DOM which in simple terms is the page. What makes rendering different to normal HTML is that it's written in JSX which stands for JavaScript XML. This allows you to add on to your JavaScript code with mark-up code. By combining both JavaScript and mark-up it allows you to do things such as conditional rendering and passing variables directly into your page.

An example of this is:

```
<p>{name}</p>
```

In this example, a paragraph is rendered to the page with the name variable being the text within it.

Comment: thanks brother but if you can eleborate it more then please..

Comment: ok brother so basically rendering mean can we say that to show or present the page(webPage)??

Comment: Yeah rendering is just presenting your code to the virtual DOM (the page).

Comment: How come you haven't accepted my edit.

Comment: i have accepted brother